# "The Service is currently not available." error for Maximo Anywhere Windows apps

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am having hard time making windows version of MaximoAnywhere working.
I am using Windows Surface Pro3 with Windows 10 OS as target device. I am also having development setup in the same machine i.e eclipse and visual studio.
I am using Maximo Anywhere 7521 4q release.
I have generated appx file for AssetAudit, but not able to upload this to application center. I am getting "Invalid Appx file. Manifest xml file is missing for APPX application file".
As a work around I have sideloaded the app onto the device using Windows powershell.
After this, I tried to access the app and I am getting the login page. But after entering login credentials, I am getting "Service not available" error.

Same is happening for other apps also.

Followed instructions as per the below blog..
"https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/Maximo_Anywhere_7_6_it_out_Now_with_Windows_10_support?lang=en"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service not available means that the mobilefirst server cannot be reached from the mobile device.  Can you doublecheck that the server is reachable from a browser to the mobile device?

Alternatively it's possible that the AssetAudit app itself isn't running inside that MobileFirst server.  Make sure you can use the worklight console to preview the AssetAudit app.

I think that the Asset Audit application isn't fully tested on Windows tablet in the version of 4Q that you're using so that might just be a bug. It'd be better to upgrade to the the 7.6 version.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I did preliminary checking by accessing the app from the browser simulator, which was working. The issue is resolved for me now. I think it got something to do with the way I was installing the app. When I reported the issue, I was using the powershell to install the app. Today I tried to run the project from Visual Studio, which installed the app on the device. In this way, app is working fine.